# Создание нового столбца по условию. Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Очень прошу у знатоков помощи в решении задачи.

Допустим есть DataFrame:

[image: таблица1]

Я бы хотел создать "счетчик", который показывал, какое количество раз значения в столбце с1 шли от наименьшего к наибольшему. Т.е. в итоге хотел бы получить такой результат:

[image: таблица2]

Подскажите, пожалуйста! Как можно это реализовать?

Comment: Исходные данные надо приводить во вопросе в воспроизводимом виде.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Примерно так:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'cl1': [1,2,3,1,4,6,2,3,4,1]})
df['cl2'] = (~(df.cl1 > df.cl1.shift().fillna(0))).cumsum()+1
df
```

Вывод:

```
    cl1 cl2
0   1   1
1   2   1
2   3   1
3   1   2
4   4   2
5   6   2
6   2   3
7   3   3
8   4   3
9   1   4
```

Comment: CrazyElf, спасибо Вам за помощь!)